# How to permanently remove the Tittle Odoo and favicon form Taskbar

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

Good day,
How can I permanently remove the title Odoo and the favicon from navigation menu in Odoo 15.

I am looking for a solution in code, the usually way of activating the debug mode and replace the favicon doesn't work. It first loads the Odoo icon then the icon you have uploaded.

Is their a way to replace permanently both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the icon:
You can go to **Settings**>**General Settings**>**Manage Companies** and change the **Company favicon** field.
But if you want a code solution you can:
Step 1:  Override the web module with your own module.
Step 2:  Add the icon to your module folder under static/src/img
Step 3:  Change the x_icon value

For the title:
You will have to override the init function in the abstract_web_client.js and call set('title_part', {"zopenerp": "My New Title"});

example:

```
WebClient.include({
          init: function(parent, action, options) {
              this._super.apply(this, arguments);
              this.set('title_part', {"zopenerp": 'My New Title'});
          }
      });
```